# Query column for multiple values

Tags: php, sql, search

I have a table that looks somewhat like the one below, and I am doing a search query with multiple fields to refine a search for a job. At the moment I am able to enter into multiple fields, however, my search results query the entire database, not just for one specific ID.

Table:

```
    contentId   meta_key        meta_value  
    1   1       vacancyType     Hospitality   
    2   1       vacancyRole     Chef       
    3   1       vacancyDate     2014-01-01     
    4   2       vacancyType     Adin   
    5   2       vacancyArea     St Albans       
    6   2       vacancyDate     2014-01-01
```

Code:

```
    $getJobs1 = "SELECT distinct *
                 FROM  cms_contentExtra, cms_content
                 WHERE cms_contentExtra.meta_value  IN ('$type','$key') 
                 AND cms_content.contentId = cms_contentExtra.contentId
                 GROUP BY cms_content.contentId";        

    $getJobs2 = mysql_query($getJobs1) or die("didn't query");      
    while ($getJobs3 = mysql_fetch_array($getJobs2)) {      
        echo ' - ' . $getJobs3[meta_value] . ' - ' . ' - ' . $getJobs3[contentId];      
    }
```

This will return:

```
- St Albans - - 8435 - St Albans - - 8436 - Hospitality & Catering - - 8437 - St Albans - - 8440 - Hospitality & Catering - - 8444 - Hospitality & Catering - - 8450 - Hospitality & Catering - - 8451 - St Albans - - 8453
```

However, I only want to show results that have BOTH the area and type, and disregard the others. At the moment it seems to be displaying the type and then displaying the area separately, so I am unable to show a type in a specific area.

I am using two tables to compare the contentId to more data stored in a different table.

Comment: It is not clear what you want. You show one table, but your query contains two tables. The results you show don't match the table shown. Where does 'St Albans' suddenly come from? What is 8435? Then you ask meta_value to match one of two values ($type and $key). So what do you want to see in your results: One line per contentid and meta_value? Or one line per contentid? If the latter: Which of the two meta_value shall be shown? Why do you query meta_value without meta_key? Doesn't it matter whether the role is 'Butler' or the area is 'Butler'? Think about what you really want and tell us.

Comment: I apologize for not explaining well. I'm using another table to compare contentId. The other table simply stores the data within a bespoke CMS system, whereas the contentExtra table stores the actual content. The other table is fairly irrelevant at this point.

I have basically built a multiple search form, and am storing each search variable to compare against the table. Therefore, I need to search the same collumn for multiple queries, as the user has multiple search inputs. I want to compare the stored variables $type, and $key against the same column in the table. 

8435 is the contentID

Comment: No, I still don't understand. Maybe because you didn't answer any of my questions. I suggest you show table definitions, sample table data and desired output (that matches the sample table data).

Comment: I'll break it down for you:

STEP 1 - built a multiple input search form. pulling results and querying the database. The results are then stored into the two variables $type and $key, which hold the vacancy type searched for, and the location.

STEP 2 - I want to compare $type and $key to the meta_value cell on the table, this table holds the meta data for the job, there are other values which i will pull in the future. 

The table above is an example of how the table is set up, it holds much more data, therefore larger contentId's.

Comment: At the moment it is pulling both results seperately, so if i search st albans and choose hospitality & catering, it will pull through all the jobs in st albans, and all the hospitality & catering jobs, not just hospitality & catering jobs in st albans.

Answer (score 0):

The `IN` operand that you use is an `OR` operation.

Try to use `LIKE` such as:

```
WHERE cms_contentExtra.meta_value LIKE "%$type%$key%"
OR cms_contentExtra.meta_value LIKE "%$key%$type%"
```

Comment: No, everything else on the page is working. The query breaks here. If I change it back to the original code in the question, the page loads with no errors.

Comment: im sry, i have overseen the double quotes at the begin of the statement. try this `$getJob1 = "SELECT distinct * FROM cms_contentExtra, cms_content WHERE cms_content.contentId = cms_contentExtra.contentId AND (cms_contentExtra.meta_value LIKE '%$type%$key%' OR cms_contentExtra.meta_value LIKE '%$key%$type%') GROUP BY cms_content.contentId";`

Comment: No, the query dies before I can echo

Comment: i cant believe... please replace the vars with strings, such as: `$getJob1 = "SELECT distinct * FROM cms_contentExtra, cms_content WHERE cms_content.contentId = cms_contentExtra.contentId AND (cms_contentExtra.meta_value LIKE '%St Albans%Hospitality%' OR cms_contentExtra.meta_value LIKE '%$Hospitality%St Albans%') GROUP BY cms_content.contentId";`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64709/discussion-on-answer-by-giwwel-query-collumn-for-multiple-values).

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a closer look at your query. You group by contentId. So you get one record per contentId. But you select *. (This must be MySQL, for I don't know any other dbms allowing this.) So you get the content record belonging to the content id, and one (random) cms_contentExtra record belonging to the content id. Then you use DISTINCT, so you only get distinct rows. But the rows must be distinct, because they differ at least in the content id. Having said this, your query doesn't make sense, and I recommend you look up GROUP BY and DISTINCT in a book or tutorial. (Moreover you shouldn't use comma-separated join syntax. That was replaced more than twenty years ago with explicit joins. Use INNER JOIN instead.)  So far to this :-)

To clean things up for you, I lead you step by step. Maybe this is not exactly what you are looking for, but I think it will help you build the final query.

To get content IDs with the vacancy type $type:

```
select contentid
from cms_content
where meta_key = 'vacancyType' and meta_value = @type;
```

To get content IDs with the location $key:

```
select contentid
from cms_content
where meta_key = 'vacancyArea' and meta_value = @key;
```

To get content IDs that match $type or $key:

```
select distinct contentid
from cms_content
where (meta_key = 'vacancyType' and meta_value = @type)
or (meta_key = 'vacancyArea' and meta_value = @key);
```

To get content IDs that match both $type and $key:

```
select contentid
from cms_content
where (meta_key = 'vacancyType' and meta_value = @type)
or (meta_key = 'vacancyArea' and meta_value = @key)
group by contentid
having count(*) = 2;
```